# Round Collapsing Toolbar android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to make my collpasing toolbar have round corners when collapsed. I have an image inside of it that has rounded corners, so when the toolbar is expanded it looks like it has rounded corners, but when I collpase it the collpsed toolbar is squared. Is there a way to make it round ?

My xml:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:clickable="true"
tools:context=".ui.recipe.RecipeFragment">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:scrimAnimationDuration="100"
        app:contentScrim="@color/faded_black"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="275dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/example_picture"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:menu="@menu/recipe_menu"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae faucibus nisl, sit amet aliquam libero. Vestibulum venenatis ullamcorper lacus et aliquet. Duis tristique, mauris et tincidunt varius, dui diam feugiat lacus, vel convallis urna purus at nunc. Proin condimentum placerat viverra. Integer nec est sodales lorem porttitor congue. Aenean scelerisque sem blandit dui posuere gravida. Pellentesque in fringilla nisi, vitae bibendum mi. Fusce velit nisl, feugiat sed sollicitudin sit amet, tempus at ante. Nunc facilisis, odio nec consectetur elementum, turpis enim fringilla libero, a scelerisque nunc nulla eget est. Ut eu augue sapien. Donec rhoncus euismod consectetur. Praesent in tempor enim. Phasellus finibus, sem sit amet porta porttitor, sem diam volutpat augue, non interdum massa ante sit amet dolor. Nunc pharetra arcu condimentum augue rhoncus, et imperdiet nulla porta. Phasellus tristique mauris arcu."
            android:textSize="100dp" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Short video showing the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEOEP.jpg